# gnuplot: change labels font size and rotate labels

Tags: gnuplot

I'm plotting data with the `w labels` modifier.

Is it possible to change the font size of these labels and/or rotate them?

I've been going through the documentation and can't find anything that'll do that.

There's `set label rotate` and `set label font` but those don't seem to apply a general rule for all labels.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nevermind, I just realized I can add modifiers to the plots in this way:

```
plot "data" using 1:2:2 smooth frequency w labels rotate by 90 font "8"
```